# When query doesn't return result page doesn't load at all - using Google chart from ajax call

Tags: codeigniter, join

I have a problem with a query. I have to show all items from a table which are for a definite company. All users must see only orders for company they work no matter  which user has inserted them in database.

Problem is that when there aren't orders in ordersheader for user's company, it doesn't load page at all. How to do this query?
My query is:

```
$company = $this->session->userdata('logged_in')['company'];
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('orderitems');
$this->db->join('ordersheader', 'ordersheader.idOrder=orderitems.idOrder');
$this->db->join('customer', 'ordersheader.idCustomer=customer.idCustomer','left');
$this->db->join('systemusers', 'systemusers.idSystemUsers=ordersheader.user_id');
$this->db->where('systemusers.company', $company)
```

Edited: I'll show my full code and my view with google chart where I get data from ajax call.  think that's the problem.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
   
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
                  
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: "<?= base_url() ?>index.php/receivedOrders/column_chart/",
      dataType: "json",
      // cache: false,
      success: function(jsonData){

        drawChart(jsonData);

      }
    });              
      
 
  function drawChart(jsonData) {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    
    var options = {     
      hAxis: {
      title: '<?php echo lang("haxis_date"); ?>',
      format: 'h:mm a',
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: '<?php echo lang("chart_average_price"); ?>'
      },
      width:'400',
      height:'300',
      backgroundColor: 'none',
      colors:['#ec8f6e', '#e6693e', '#e0440c', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6'],
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3,alignment: 'center' },
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('column_chart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  });
```

My controller method where I call json data for chart is:

```html
<?php 
public function column_chart() {   
        
      $size = $this->uri->segment(3);
      $interval = $this->uri->segment(4);
      $firms = $this->Receivedorders_model->average_price_by_week($size,$interval);
     
      $p = array();
      foreach ($firms as $key => $firm) {
        $p[$key] = array('c' => array(array(
          'v' =>  $firm['interval'],  
        ),
        
     
        array(
          'v' =>  round($firm['unitPrice'],2), 
        )));
      }
      echo json_encode(array(
      'cols' => array(
          array('id' => 'name',  'label' => lang("customer"),  'type' => 'string'),
          array('id' => 'incomes', 'label' => lang("chart_average_price"),  'type' => 'number'),

        ),
        'rows' => $p

      ));
      
    }
```

Comment: Session user data is wrong `$this->session->userdata('company');`

Comment: re edit OP and show controller and full complete model function

Comment: you need to make a LEFT JOIN. Try this: `$this->db->join('ordersheader', 'ordersheader.idOrder=
     orderitems.idOrder', 'left');`

Comment: Maybe my problem is view- I show 2 google charts - for one of the charts I get data from ajax call. When I commented it, it loaded my page. I'll edit my code now to show full code.